# MacOS command line will not let me ls certain directories

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

Whenever I try to list directories/files in certain directories like:

```
~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/

~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/
```

It returns the following:
"ls: .: Operation not permitted"
I'm running MacOS 10.14.2

Any idea what's going on, or what I can do?

Comment: This question is better asked on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: Thanks for that, I will have a look at those and make better choices in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Navigate to system preferences
2. Select Security & privacy
3. Select the tab with "Privacy" and from the left side select full-disk acces
4. Unlock the tab (bottom left)
5. Click the (+) icon to add terminal to the list of full acces

Hope this helps for you

Comment: This works great.   Requires a full restart, rather than just restarting terminal, to work - but works a treat.  Thank you.